# Error "-outputfile" when building a project on gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitversion

In my project, I use the [GitVersion.MsBuild](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) library to keep track of the application version on the **wpf**.

When building in gitlab there is an

```bash
error MSB3073: 
exit command ..\net48/gitversion.exe C:\gitlab-runner\builds\...\imgupd\Wpf \
             -output file -outputfile C:\gitlab-runner\builds\DN7xGEXb\0\...\Wpf/gitversion.json" \
with code 1. 
[C:\gitlab-runner\builds\DN7xGEXb\0\..\Wpf.csproj]
```

Has anyone else encountered this problem?
The network says that the problem has been solved with the release of a new version of the `GitVersion.MsBuild` library, but I still get this error.

My gitlab-ci file looks like this

```
variables:
  EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER: 'Wpf\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1'
  NUGET_PATH: 'C:\NuGet\nuget.exe'
  MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe'
  ARTIFACTS_NAME: "imgupd"
stages:
  - build
 #- test
  - deploy

build_job:
  stage: build
  before_script:
  - CHCP 65001
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
  script:
    - '& "$env:NUGET_PATH" restore' # restore Nuget dependencies
    - '& "$env:MSBUILD_PATH" /p:Configuration=Release /clp:ErrorsOnly' # build the project
    - '$deployFolder = $($env:ARTIFACTS_NAME) + "\"'
    - 'xcopy /y /e ".\$env:EXE_RELEASE_FOLDER\*" "$deployFolder"'
  artifacts:
    name: "$env:ARTIFACTS_NAME"
    expire_in: 1 week # save gitlab server space, we copy the files we need to deploy folder later on
    paths:
      - '$env:ARTIFACTS_NAME\' # saving exe to copy to deploy folder
     #- '$env:MSI_RELEASE_FOLDER\Configurator Setup.msi' # saving msi to copy to deploy folder

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - CHCP 65001
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: on_success
      allow_failure: false
script:
  - '$commitSubject = git log -1 --pretty=%s'

dependencies:
  - build_job
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still reported and followed with [`GitTools/GitVersion` issue 2993](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2993).

It does include the caveat (for GitHub Actions):

> For GitVersion to execute successfully, it needs the full repository history.
>
> By default, `actions/checkout` does a shallow clone. Add the following to the workflow and it should at least be able to execute:
>
> ```yaml
>    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
>      with:
>        fetch-depth: 0
> ```

Double-check in your gitlab-ci if you have [a shallow clone (IE: `GIT_DEPTH` set)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/large_repositories/#shallow-cloning).

If not, check if this is related to [issue 2534](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2534): Build error due to malformed file path `obj\/gitversion.json`, since your error message also include such a `\/` path separator combination.

Comment: uses: .. 
I added it to the GitVersion.yml file did not help. Although now I'm wondering, is it really necessary to add it there?

Comment: @Arthas Again, what I mention is for GitHub Action, not GitLab, where the option would be set differently (as mentioned: `GIT_DEPTH`). But in your case, double-check you outputfile path. It includes both `\` and `/`, which could trigger the error message.

Comment: I don't understand .yml very well and added my code with gitalb-ci 
Is the \/ error corrected in this file? I can't see my error.
I took this code from another non-my project

Comment: @Arthas I believe this is generated by GitVersion itself. What version of that plugin do you have? 5.6.4 or more should be OK, according to [PR 2547](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/pull/2547).